# how to search a document split across many webpages

Tags: search

A university catalog is split on many webpages according to the hierarchy of the university, as opposed to, say, a single PDF document. There is a root URL and then various departments are under that root. Suppose I want to search for the word "calculus" in the entire catalog. How do I do that?

For example how do I search every page under [this link](https://www.lamar.edu/catalog/degrees-and-programs/degree-course-requirements/) for the word "calculus"?

Comment: Best option; google, assuming the webpages are publicly available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google: "calculus site:[https://www.lamar.edu/catalog/degrees-and-programs/"](https://www.lamar.edu/catalog/degrees-and-programs/%22)

Basically, use the prefix `site:` and qualify the parent page. It appears to work (i.e. google seems to not simply use the web-root)